# Question on Time, Speed and Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A child while going to school reduces his speed to 4/5th of his actual
>   speed and reaches 15 minutes late. Find his actual speed.

My attempt:

Speed is in the ratio = 5:4

Distance is constant.

Therefore, time is in the ratio = 4:5

Therefore, the actual time taken to reach school = 60 minuites.

From here, I am not able to find the actual speed. Please help regarding this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's not enough data to calculate the speed.

The same distance travelled
$$s=vt$$
can be covered in the time longer by $15\,\text{min}$ at $\frac 45$ of the original speed:
$$s=\frac45v(t+15\,\text{min})$$
so
$$vt=\frac45v(t+15\,\text{min})$$
and $v$ disappears, as well as $s$.

You can only find, as you did, $t$:
$$\frac54t=t+15\,\text{min}$$
$$\frac14t=15\,\text{min}$$
$$t=4\cdot 15\,\text{min} = 60\,\text{min}$$

You can get arbitrary $v$ by choosing appropriate $s=v\cdot{1\,\text{h}}.$

Answer (score 1):

We have

- $\frac {D} v=t $
- $\frac {D} {\frac{4v}5}=t+15 $

then

- $\frac54 t=t+15 \implies t=60$ min

and thus we can only deduce that

- $v=\frac {D} {60}$ km/min $=D$ km/h

Answer (score 1):

Let the actual speed $100x$ m/minute and he normally takes $y$ minutes

So, the distance  $100xy$ m

Now $100xy=80x(y+15)\implies5y=4(y+15)\iff y=60$

So, any finite value of $x$ will satisfy the given condition.

Comment: So, we cannot find any particular value for speed?

Comment: @Soumee, Yes insufficient data